# Is it possible to run a project in vc++ without dsw file. I have all the cpp and h files only but not the other supporting files

Tags: visual-c++

Is it possible to run a project in vc++ without dsw file. I have all the cpp and h files only  but not the other supporting files.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you may have to guess at the type of application. If it's a console application, go to File > New > Project > Visual C++ > Win32 > Win32 Console Application and then in the Wizard under "Additional Options" you can specify "Empty Project". Then you just right-click the project in solution explorer, then Add > Existing Item. You'll also need to supply any libraries etc. needed under Project > Properties. Without any further information, I can't be more specific, sorry. Hope this helps.